# fwrite saves same message multiple times

Tags: php, logging, fwrite

I use fwrite in php to log some errors in logs.txt.

The problem is that when I open db_errors.txt I see the message saved multiple times instead of just once.

My fwrite code is not inside any loop, so it is definately executed only once. Same think happended using third party logger classes.

```
if (!$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
    $today = getdate();
    $handle = fopen("logs/db_errors.txt", "a");
    fwrite($handle, $today['mday'].'/'.$today['mon'].'/'.$today['year']." | ".mysqli_errno($link)." : ".mysqli_error($link)." | ".$query." \n");
    fclose($handle);
}
```

this writes in 3 lines inside db_errors.txt with the same output.

```
11/4/2011 | 1054 : Unknown column 'uids' in 'field list' | SELECT uids FROM users WHERE user_id=6 LIMIT 1 
11/4/2011 | 1054 : Unknown column 'uids' in 'field list' | SELECT uids FROM users WHERE user_id=6 LIMIT 1 
11/4/2011 | 1054 : Unknown column 'uids' in 'field list' | SELECT uids FROM users WHERE user_id=6 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What about showing us your code?

Comment: title of question is kind of funny, given the question

Comment: What does "code is not inside [...] any self invoked function" mean? How can it be called if you don't invoke it?

Comment: You open the file with `a`. You are sure the other entries are not from an older execution? @netcoder: A little bit curious description, but I bet he means "recursion" :)

Comment: I think this is normal since mysqli_error could echo multiple error messages, whould you post the content of db_errors.txt.

Comment: I edited my question many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My fwrite code is not inside any loop, so it is definately executed only once. Same think happended using third party logger classes.

If *someone else's code* shows the same behavior, then you have only one possible root cause: The code is being called three times.

It's probably time to [get out a debugger](http://xdebug.org/) and [add a breakpoint](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) to your code, then step through everything that happens after the first call.  This will undoubtedly lead you to the source of the later calls.

You might also want to consider adding a full timestamp and a microtime to the log instead of `getdate`.  This may make troubleshooting more effective by proving that there are indeed three calls being made.

```
$time_plus_micro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . microtime(true)
fwrite($handle, $time_plus_micro . " | ...";
```

Comment: I used the netbeans debbuger. It turns out that the script (to be accurate index.php) iterates 3 times. I really cannot understand why. I use my own mvc framework and mod_rewrite to target every request to index.php. I understand now that the debugger was the obvious way to solve my problem but I am a beginner and it was my first to use it.